# R reset counter based on two columns

Tags: r

I have following kind of data and i need output as the second data frame...

```
a <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
b <- c(1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,4,5,6)
d <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)


df <- as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,d))


output <- c(1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,3,4)
df_output <- as.data.frame(cbind(df,output))
```

I have tried cumsum and I am not able to get the desired results. Please guide. Regards, Enthu.

---

based on column a value cahnges and if b is to be reset starting from one.

the condition is if b has same value it should start with 1.

Like in the 5th record, col b has  value as 3. It should reset to 1 and if all the values if col b is same ( as the case from ro 6,6,7,8 is same , then it should be 1 and any change should increment by 1).

Comment: Try `library(dplyr);df %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(out = match(b, unique(b)))` or `df %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(out = as.integer(factor(b)))`

Comment: giving an error

Comment: can you send send me out....library(dplyr);
 df %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(out = match(b, unique(b))) | df %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(out = as.integer(factor(b))) ...       a    b    d  out
 [1,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
 [2,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
 [3,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
 [4,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
 [5,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
 [6,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
 [7,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
 [8,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
 [9,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[10,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[11,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

Comment: `df %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(out = match(b, unique(b))) %>% .$out#
 [1] 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 3 4`

Comment: Also, I created the data.frame in a straightforward way `df <- data.frame(a, b, d)`

Comment: excellent I got it.. thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a group by column 'a' and then create the new column with either `match` the `unique` values in 'b'

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>%
          group_by(a) %>%
          mutate(out = match(b, unique(b))) 

df2
# A tibble: 11 x 4
# Groups:   a [2]
#       a     b     d   out
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1     1     1     1     1
# 2     1     1     2     1
# 3     1     1     3     1
# 4     1     2     4     2
# 5     2     3     1     1
# 6     2     3     2     1
# 7     2     3     3     1
# 8     2     3     4     1
# 9     2     4     5     2
#10     2     5     6     3
#11     2     6     7     4
```

---

Or another option is to coerce a `factor` variable to `integer`

```
df %>%
    group_by(a) %>%
    mutate(out = as.integer(factor(b)))
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(a, b, d)
```